# Convert ArrayList<xyz> to ArrayList<Float>

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

I am fairly new to `ArrayList` and I'm just trying to use different `ArrayList`. The `ArrayList<xyz>` is of type float. I use this to store values in a database in Sqlite. Later, I try to move the stored values to an `Arraylist<float>`. I know both are of different types but is there way to do conversion. Any kind of help is appreciated.

The following is the code:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TemperatureManager";

    private static final String TABLE_TEMPERATURE_READING = "Temperature";


    private static final String TEMPERATURE_READING = "name";


    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "create table " + TABLE_TEMPERATURE_READING + "("
                 + TEMPERATURE_READING + " FLOAT"+")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TEMPERATURE_READING);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }


    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new contact
    void addContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(TEMPERATURE_READING, contact.getName()); 


        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_TEMPERATURE_READING, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single contact
    Contact getContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_TEMPERATURE_READING, new String[] {
                        TEMPERATURE_READING},null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Contact contact = new Contact(cursor.getFloat(0));
        // return contact
        return contact;
    }

    // Getting All Contactsc
    public ArrayList<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        ArrayList<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TEMPERATURE_READING;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                Contact contact = new Contact();
                //contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getFloat(1));
                //contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }



    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TEMPERATURE_READING;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

        //cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
}
```

Comment: @SumeetSingh yes, I know it's very trivial question but i need some advise.

Comment: So the class xyz has float variables in it which are initialized using constructors?

Comment: @SumeetSingh yes, they are initialized using constructors

Comment: This will do the required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following function to your class xyz.

```
public Float floatValue()
{
 return this.f;
}
```

Assuming that f is the float variable of class xyz.

Now you can populate the arraylist as:Assuming list_of_objects is the arraylist of objects of class xyz.

```
Arraylist<float> al=new Arraylist<float>();
for(xyz o: list_of_objects)
 al.add(o.floatValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

You must iterate over your ArrayList and, for each value, make the transformation and store it in your ArrayList. Try the next code:

```
ArrayList<xyz> a1 = new ArrayList<xyz>();

//set the data in a1....

ArrayList<Float> a2 = new ArrayList<Float>();
int n = a1.size();

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    a2.add(a1.get(i).methodXYZtoFloat());
```

In the method **methodXYZtoFloat** (*it will return a Float*) you must define the conversion of XYZ to Float.

Hope it helps!

Comment: How do I define the conversion. ?

Comment: Well, it depends on your Java class. If you can pass a copy of the code (e.g. http://pastebin.com/) I will try to help you as much as I can!